# S7 data recovery with broken screen

Tags: backup, data-recovery, broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have a galaxy S7 (SM-G930F) with a broken screen. It can receive calls and texts and connect to wifi. I can access it via https://findmymobile.samsung.com/ to unlock it. That site also has options to back up data but they seem to hang without doing anything.

If I connect it to the computer via usb it is recognised but shows no files present to copy.
The phone has access to my wifi.

I have tried downloading several supposedly different programs for data recovery. 
One thing that is really confusing me is that most of them seem to be variations of the exact same program dr. fone but with different product names. What is going on there? 
For instance isky toolbox = dr. fone

Some of them don't support S7 (even despite being the same programs as each other). They threaten to risk bricking the phone if the wrong model is selected.

I do not have usb debugging enabled (at least I don't recall enabling it, though I possibly install some apps that might have such as a Linux terminal program I don't remember and can no longer check)

I'm am also trying up the contents of the SDcard. I'm not sure what's it and isn't on there. ie. in the Android directory. Windows refuses to transfer the files itself (if I select all of them it copies nothing). It also suggested it would take >1 day to backup a subset of the media files (~9Gb). so I need to use a different copy tool. I am currently trying AOMEI Backupper. This has not yet completed even counting the files to copy.

What are my options for recovering files such as photos or other data like app settings, game progress, whatsapp messages or whatever?
I'm not sure what's on the SD card versus the internal storage.
I have the option to use either Linux, PC or even iPad for this.

Replacing the screen or some other hardware repair is not an option.

I have since moved my sim card to a new phone (different model) but could move it back if that would make any difference.

airdroid looks like a good way to get around this kind of problem except that I have to have installed it before I broke my phone.
Some of the backup/recovery programs look like they work by pushing an app onto the phone somehow. Being able to push one of them or something like airdroid would be great.

Similar questions:

- [Access files or ADB on locked Galaxy S7 with broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202093/access-files-or-adb-on-locked-galaxy-s7-with-broken-screen)
- [Enable ADB and/or change USB connection mode on Galaxy S7 w/ broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/enable-adb-and-or-change-usb-connection-mode-on-galaxy-s7-w-broken-screen)

They don't quite help me though.

Comment: Basically...the new phones have a choice for USB modes. It's probably stuck in USB charging mode by default. You need to switch it to MTP. If your touchscreen seems to still work, you can try to unlock it then go at it blindly. Use this video to approximate where to press on the screen. https://youtu.be/pZzIU5ErC4I?t=80  Once in MTP mode, windows will be able to access the files.

Comment: I would have previously set it to MTP mode, so it should still be in it, unless something can reset it.

Comment: MTP is not working on lock screen. enter your pin or password (see the "not helpful" duplicates). besides this, depending on build.prop for some devices you have to select MTP in developer options each time after connect (don't know if this is a bug or feature)